# I'm sending firebase notification with PHP and Postman, but the message isn't sent

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm sending firebase notification with PHP, but the message isn't sent. The notification seems to have been sent, but it does not. I tried again with POSTMAN and reached the same result. I want to send notifications to all users.

```
<?php

define('API_ACCESS_KEY','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$fcmUrl = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

$notification = [
    'title' =>'TITLE',
    'body' => 'MESSAGE.'
];
$extraNotificationData = ["message" => $notification,"moredata" =>'dd'];

$fcmNotification = [
            'to'        => "/topics/all",
            'notification' => $notification,
            'data' => $extraNotificationData
        ];

        $headers = [
            'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ];


        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$fcmUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fcmNotification));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        echo $result;
        ?>
```

Returned data

`{"message_id":4709853598141003946}`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your variables are correct and the topic is case sensitive, I capitalized my "A" in "all" and it worked just fine for me.

Comment: @Aksoyhlc See if changing the arrays to array() instead of []. When I put your code on my website, it showed errors because [] isn't valid in php.